# SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMd‌dHH:mm:ss") has issue on groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I call groovy script in Jenkins pipeline.

```
def start_time = new Date()
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMd‌​dHH:mm:ss")
println sdf.format(start_time)
```

But I get "20160817‌​1708:34:35", the day has been output twice.
So I test it on my local machine with groovy, and I get the same result.

Any thing I missed?

Comment: Yes, at last I get the correct result in groovy. 
I type in another file. But I don't the reason is the non-ASCII/Unicode characters.
Thanks for your investigation.

Comment: macking_liu, you haven't accepted any of the answers. Don't know how to [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Yes, the 1st "d" is problematic. VS Code complains: "The character U+200c is invisible."

Answer (score 8):

I believe there are non-ASCII/Unicode characters in the format string. (They were clear when I pasted the code into Vim.) I have removed them and this works fine:

```
import java.text.*

def start_time = new Date()
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss")
println sdf.format(start_time)
```

Answer (score 8):

Michael is right, there is problem with the text provided in the question.

By the way, in groovy, one can directly format on the `Date` object without using `SimpleDateFormat` like below and does the same:

```
println new Date().format​('yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss')
```

**Output**

```
2016081711:04:17
```